# "Hello World" program has generated an exception

Tags: java

I am new to Java and its my first program in Java, I am trying to run "Hello World" App program but its giving an error. It has compiled but has generated this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
HelloWorldApp/class Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
HelloWorldApp.class at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
```

---

I wrote the given code in Note Pad and saved that in `C:\Program Files x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_14\bin`

code:

```
public class HelloWorldApp{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you compile it before running? javac.. did this ring any bell?

Comment: if you don't want the overhead of having to compile locally, try an online java compiler: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php its is especially useful if you want to run a quick test or practice

Comment: Compile it, javac helloworldapp.java and then run it java helloworldapp

Comment: I had run that earlier and that is generated an error 
c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_14\bin>javac HelloWorldApp.java"
HelloWorldApp.java:5: error while writing HelloWorldApp: HelloWorldApp: HelloWorldApp.class (Access is denied)
public class HelloWorldApp(
1 error
But that was overcome by running it in administrative privilage.  But now it gives the error that I have requested for, earilier.

Comment: Your error looks like you're typing `java HelloWorldApp.class` instead of `java HelloWorldApp` to run it.  Can you confirm?  If this is the case, then just leave off the `.class`.

Answer (score 3):

Remeber that you must use specific filename in java so:

- If your class is `HelloWorldApp`, you must put it into a file named `HelloWorldApp.java`
- Then you must compile with `javac HelloWorldApp.java`.
- Now, you can execute the result .class file with `java HelloWorldApp`

Comment: Isn't `java HelloWorldApp.class` supposed to be `java HelloWorldApp`?

Answer (score 1):

use only class, not public class.

public class can only be used when your java code file name is same as your public class name in which your main method is present.

use

```
 class HelloWorldApp{
 public static void main(String[] args){
 System.out.println("Hello World");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The runtime's not finding the actual class file, rather than any issue with the code itself.  For a starter though, you should be working in your own folder tree and be treating anything under "Program Files" as Read-only and not anywhere to be creating files.

Create your own folder elsewhere, compile then run, possibly specify the class path when running.